# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '': When trying to use child routes and Ng2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have [the following plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PHaGNtfa0fPBgET4NEpZ?p=preview), which does not work. In order to get it to work I can comment out...

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
          path: "",
          component: TestComponent,
          children: [
              // {
              //    path:"",
              //    outlet: "other",
              //    component: TestComponent
              // }
          ]
      }
])
```

If I don't do that I get...

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
```

How do I add a child route?

Answer (score 2):

You should give different path names until you use `pathMatch: 'full'`. [Forked](https://plnkr.co/edit/6tWj2a1EiZPdeuADWAHk?p=preview).

More about the subject in [Angular Router: Empty Paths, Componentless Routes, and Redirects](http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes).

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding this, but I want to show both not just one. So I want to show the parent and the child.

Comment: Indeed, you can see my plnkr

Comment: I must be missing something, this looks like it only has a child if you go to `#/test` or whatever and I don't see a link to get there. Also I don't see the outlet, I thought you needed that to declare which of the outlets should be replaced. I would think if there was one test component inside of the other test component then we should see the `this is the test` text twice right?

Comment: For example here is a plunker with 2 different components https://plnkr.co/edit/Nb6AmerB4jMtAu8abDCq?p=preview. I see the Test one but I don't see the test 2 one

Comment: Don't you see the outlet? So what is printed in the child component? I will not see your second plunk, it's not related to the problem `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:`

Comment: Ok I fought through it and I get here...

https://plnkr.co/edit/asz3imPxty0xVFpkHIUX?p=preview 

This allows me to do what I want but the syntax of the URL is real strange... 

`https://run.plnkr.co/gvIdVsgjFwTdaHCy/#/test/(other:area2)`

Comment: The problem is not just why do I get that message, it is why do I get it when I try to add children but not when they are commented out.

Comment: I can't figure out it from your post. If you need to clarify your question, go and edit it.

Comment: @Jackie I have updated a plunk, you were right there should be two `this is the test` output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128065/discussion-between-jackie-and-roman-c).

Answer (score 1):

The router will stop after the first path is matched,  which it does in the parent route. I've found it best to use a separate routing module for each router outlet. That being said, you get an ugly `(other:route)` for the auxilary route in your url. Admittedly, I have found some limitations to using auxiliary routes.