# Sometimes Routing is not working properly

Tags: angular

I am building ananglar app in which all thing working fine except routing only on some condition or some times.

I am using this to navigate to main page:

> this._router.navigate(['']);

```
export const LoginRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignUpComponent
    }
];
```

when i on page :

> http://localhost:3000/dashboard/viewproduct

and click logout button inside which i am navigating to login component sometime its working perfectly but, sometime its getting stucked and navigates me on the same page i.e:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/viewproduct
```

I cannot able to figure out whats happing wrong??
Please suggest if anybody else also faced this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '': When trying to use child routes and Ng2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566685/cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment-when-trying-to-use-child-routes-and-ng)

Comment: Hmmm...not sure but its working fine all the time. Just i have logged in to my application and let it idle for 30 minutes then i faced this issue. Again after clearing the history its working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have empty path routes without `children` or `redirectTo` then use `pathMatch: 'full'` like

```
export const LoginRoutes: Route[] = [
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
```

to tell the router it can stop trying to match further routes.

Comment: this is also not working. But, after cleaning the history its again working

Comment: Use `this._router.navigate(['/']);` with a `/`, otherwise the router will assume a route relative to your current route. Route definitions should **not** have a leading `/`, but absolute routes in `routerLink` or `router.navigate(...)` should.

Comment: What is `dashboard` and `viewproduct`? Your question doesn't provide any hint where they come from.

Comment: ok dashboard is my home screen where i have different menu , viewproduct is a part of menu. The default page is login after login dashboard will come with top navigation. On clicking view product it will be routed to viewproduct page.

Comment: Please add the code (routes) to your question that makes that obvious. Sorry, but I'm not able to reason about your problem with some disconnected code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction:**
I encountered the same problem. But finally found that **the issue is with the anchor tag** in html.

**Cause:**
If the routerLink is given in anchor tag within a button tag **the routerLink will not get activated until the anchor text is clicked specifically**.

**Solution:**
Give the router link within the button tag.

**Example**

Correct

```
<button routerLink="/home"> Home </button>
```

Wrong

```
<button> <a routerLink="/home"> Home </a> </button>
```